# Wrong IP address in ssh restart

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, debian, dns-zone

I've just set up a second vps (s2.example.com) and when trying to restart SSH I'm getting the following error:

"The authenticity of host 'restart (xxx.xxx.xxx.74)' can't be established."

The IP address (ending .74) is not the IP address of that server. It is the IP address of another vps running at www.example.com.

I've set an A record for s2 to point to the correct IP address for that server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: BTW pinging s2.example.com shows the correct IP address

Comment: What's the command you're running?

Comment: @Dennis: ssh restart

Comment: I think @MadHatter is on the right track, I've got a wildard in the zonefile so 'restart' would translate to the IP of the server at www

Comment: `service ssh restart` did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `service sshd restart`! `ssh restart` is an instruction to make an ssh connection to the host called restart (hence the error message).

And while I'm turning this into an actual answer, may I put in a plea - not just to you, DavidM, but to anyone who asks a question on SF - to post as much detail as they can about what they *did*, not just what they were *trying to do*.  Dennis' question cracked this one wide-open, but he should never have had to ask it.  I highly recommend the accepted answer to [this meta question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) to anyone thinking of asking a question on SF.

Comment: Sorry I'm a n00b here. Thought I'd added as much as anyone would need with 'trying to restart ssh' but I guess that's vague!

Comment: We totally got what you were **trying** to do, that bit was excellent.  The problem lay in **how** you were trying to do it.  A post that said "I tried to restart the ssh service with `ssh restart` but I only got the following error message..." would have saved a whole half-hour.  Does that make sense?